# Цикл таблицы в php с информацией из БД

Tags: php, mysql

```
<?php 
    include_once('/setting.php');

    $db = mysql_connect('localhost', 'логин', 'пороль');

    mysql_select_db('бд', $db);

    $result = mysql_query(' SELECT * FROM tableEpson ');
    $myrow = mysql_fetch_array($result);

    echo '<table class='table' border='1'><tr>';

    while ($myrow = mysql_fetch_array($result)) {
        printf('<td>%s</td> <td>%s</td> <td>%s</td> <td>%s</td> <td>%s</td> <td>%s</td> <td>%s</td>',
$myrow['Model'], $myrow['CartridgeNumber'], $myrow['1psc'], $myrow['2-3psc'], $myrow['4-6psc'], $myrow['7-10psc'], $myrow['11-13psc']);
        echo '</tr></table>';  
    }

    echo '</tr></table>';
?>
```

Ребят, помогите, кто сможет, а то уже все мозги кипят. У меня, вообщем, есть БД, в которой хранится Прайс лист обслуживания техники. Так вот, мне нужно эту БД вывести в Тег *table* в *index.php* и чтобы вывелось все в цикле в *td*. Я прописал скрипт цикла, но видать что-то не так. У меня в первой строке *td* появилось все как нужно, а вот след инфа т.е. *id2* *id3* и т.д. не в таблице, но они на экране вышли. Подскажите что не так.

Comment: `tr`  у вас вне цикла стоит..... поэтому создается только одна строка....... точнее внутри цикла стоит `echo '</tr></table>';`  ......собсн ошибка раз, ибо table закрывается в цикле ..... `tr` не открывается в цикле - ошибка два

Answer (score -1):

```
<?php 
    include_once('/setting.php');

    $db = mysql_connect('localhost', 'логин', 'пороль');

    mysql_select_db('бд', $db);

    $result = mysql_query(' SELECT * FROM tableEpson ');
    $myrow = mysql_fetch_array($result);

    echo '<table class='table' border='1'>';

    while ($myrow = mysql_fetch_array($result)) {
        printf('<tr><td>%s</td> <td>%s</td> <td>%s</td> <td>%s</td> <td>%s</td> <td>%s</td> <td>%s</td>',
$myrow['Model'], $myrow['CartridgeNumber'], $myrow['1psc'], $myrow['2-3psc'], $myrow['4-6psc'], $myrow['7-10psc'], $myrow['11-13psc']);
        echo '</tr>';  
    }

    echo '</tr></table>';
?>
```